# Validate lineitems and throw error if the lineitem values dont match

Tags: apex

On the OpportunityLineItem, I have 2 custom lookup fields and 2 text fields. So if I have like 5 line items added, and if the 2 lookup fields match on any 2 lineitems, I need to make sure the other 2 text fields match as well. Below is the code-

```
public static void validatelineItems(Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> mapOpptyLineItem){  
    
    List<string> addLoc; 
    
    for(id oli : mapOpptyLineItem.keyset()) {
    
        if(mapOpptyLineItem.get(oli).lookup_fld1__c != null && mapOpptyLineItem.get(oli).lookup_fld2__c != null) {
            String cpe = String.valueOf(mapOpptyLineItem.get(oli).lookup_fld1__c) + String.valueOf(mapOpptyLineItem.get(oli).lookup_fld2__c);   

            if(addLoc.contains(cpe)) {     
                hasduplicates = true; //This tells that there are lineitems with the same lookup values.
            }

            addLoc.add(cpe); 

            //Now we need to loop through the map to check if the text field value matches and am not sure how to do that.
        } 
    }
}
```

Ex:

```
fields         - Lookupfld1 Lookupfld2 textfld1 txtfld2
Record1 values -  id1         id2        t1       t2
Record2 values -  id1         id2        t1       t4
```

so in the above example, both the lookup field ids have matched but the text fld2 didnt match, so it should throw the error.

Comment: What did you try and what errors are you running into?

Comment: I m not sure how we can compare 2 records using a map. I tried using a for loop within the map.keyset() but I m not sure how to check record1 and record2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps and Sets are your friend whenever you want to perform pretty much any comparison.

The general approach here is:

- Determine what you want your map key to be, and what you want the value to be
- Make the key, and check to see if it exists in the map already
- If it doesn't, then put the key into the map along with the value
- If it does, then grab the value from the map and compare it against the value you currently have

You can use SObjects as the key of a map (and this is a fantastic way to quickly perform complex comparisons), you just need to be very careful to never make a change to the SObject instance that you use as a key *after you put it into the map*.

I'd suggest making a `Map<OpportunityLineItem, OpportunityLineItem>` here. The OLI key would just contain your two lookup fields (and probably also the OpportunityId), and the OLI that you store would only contain your two text fields. That'd end up looking something like this

```java
Map<OpportunityLineItem, OpportunityLineItem> oliKeyToOLITarget = new Map<OpportunityLineItem, OpportunityLineItem>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oli :myOLIs){
    // Create the key object
    OpportunityLineItem oliKey = new OpportunityLineItem(
        My_Lookup_1__c = oli.My_Lookup_1__c,
        My_Lookup_2__c = oli.My_Lookup_2__c
    );

    // Create the target value object
    OpportunityLineItem oliValue = new OpportunityLineItem(
        My_Field_1__c = oli.My_Field_1__c,
        My_Field_2__c = oli.My_Field_2__c
    );

    // Check to see if the key exists in the map and, if it does, if the value matches
    if(oliKeyToOLITarget.containsKey(oliKey) && oliKeyToOLITarget.get(oliKey) != oliValue){
        // The key matches, but the value doesn't
        // emit an error, then "continue;" to skip to the next loop iteration
    }

    // Now that oliKey is being put into the map as a key, this instance of OLI should
    //   never be modified.
    // It's ok to create a new OLI instance and store it in the same variable
    //   (using the `new` keyword is the most sure way to get a completely new and
    //    independent instance)
    // It's ok to overwrite the map value at this point, because this is either the first time
    //   this key is being used, or the new value is the same as the old value
    oliKeyToOLITarget.put(oliKey, oliValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek. I actually want both the lookup fields to match, and if they do, thats when I should look for the other text field values. I tried to concatenate both the lookup fields and use that as key in Map<string, opportunitylineitem> but if there are lineitems with same lookup values, its not getting added to the map. I guess because map key doesnt accept duplicates.

Comment: @Kushitin That's precisely what this approach does. You include both of the lookup fields in the object instance that you use as the map key, and they both get taken into consideration when you `map.containsKey()`. That's the power behind using an `SObject` as a map key (and it also doesn't require any concatenation).

Comment: When we do map.containsKey(), it would return true even if one lookupfield matches. I want both the lookup fields to be matched on all the lineitem records.

Comment: @Kushitin That is not correct. The containsKey() call will only return true if all SObject fields of the key are present and match (and there are no additional fields included on the SObject key you're giving to `containsKey()`).

Comment: I didnt know that you can use sobject this way. This is amazing. Thanks so much. I just tried for one field and that worked.

Comment: Regd the values object, instead of adding the fields manually, I want to use a lst that has the field api;s. I tried this but that didnt work. Any suggestions? `List<string> flds = new list<string>{'fld1__c','fld2__c','fld3__c','fld4__c'};for(string s: flds){                         OpportunityLineItem oliValue = new OpportunityLineItem(s = mapOpptyLineItem.get(oppli).s;                                                                                                             }`